# Simple Angular model-binding not working?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my html and script,

```
<div class="gallery-env" ng-app="s" np-controller="ProductCtrl">
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="product in products">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <article class="album">
                <header>
                    <a href="extra-gallery-single.html">
                        <img src="{{product.Image.Path}}" />
                    </a>
                    <a href="#" class="album-options">
                        <i class="entypo-cog"></i>
                        Change Cover
                    </a>
                </header>
                <section class="album-info">
                    <h3><a href="extra-gallery-single.html">{{product.Name}}</a></h3>
                    <p>{{product.ShortDescription}}</p>
                </section>
            </article>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="/Scripts/angular.1.3.0-beta.5.min.js"></script>
<script>
    (function() {
        var app = angular.module('s', []);
        app.controller('ProductCtrl', function($scope) {
            $scope.products = [{"Name":"Album Title","Price":0.0,"NewPrice":0.0,"ShortDescription":"Can curiosity may end shameless explained. True high on said mr on come.","SKU":"","ProductTypeID":0,"ImageID":2,"Promotion":"","ParentID":0,"Attributes":"","Image":{"Path":"http://demo.neontheme.com/assets/images/album-thumb-1.jpg","Id":2},"Reviews":[],"Id":5101},{"Name":"Album Title","Price":0.0,"NewPrice":0.0,"ShortDescription":"Can curiosity may end shameless explained. True high on said mr on come.","SKU":"","ProductTypeID":0,"ImageID":2,"Promotion":"","ParentID":0,"Attributes":"","Image":{"Path":"http://demo.neontheme.com/assets/images/album-thumb-1.jpg","Id":2},"Reviews":[],"Id":5102},{"Name":"Album Title","Price":0.0,"NewPrice":0.0,"ShortDescription":"Can curiosity may end shameless explained. True high on said mr on come.","SKU":"","ProductTypeID":0,"ImageID":2,"Promotion":"","ParentID":0,"Attributes":"","Image":{"Path":"http://demo.neontheme.com/assets/images/album-thumb-1.jpg","Id":2},"Reviews":[],"Id":5103},{"Name":"Album Title","Price":0.0,"NewPrice":0.0,"ShortDescription":"Can curiosity may end shameless explained. True high on said mr on come.","SKU":"","ProductTypeID":0,"ImageID":2,"Promotion":"","ParentID":0,"Attributes":"","Image":{"Path":"http://demo.neontheme.com/assets/images/album-thumb-1.jpg","Id":2},"Reviews":[],"Id":5104},{"Name":"Album Title","Price":0.0,"NewPrice":0.0,"ShortDescription":"Can curiosity may end shameless explained. True high on said mr on come.","SKU":"","ProductTypeID":0,"ImageID":2,"Promotion":"","ParentID":0,"Attributes":"","Image":{"Path":"http://demo.neontheme.com/assets/images/album-thumb-1.jpg","Id":2},"Reviews":[],"Id":5105},{"Name":"Album Title","Price":0.0,"NewPrice":0.0,"ShortDescription":"Can curiosity may end shameless explained. True high on said mr on come.","SKU":"","ProductTypeID":0,"ImageID":2,"Promotion":"","ParentID":0,"Attributes":"","Image":{"Path":"http://demo.neontheme.com/assets/images/album-thumb-1.jpg","Id":2},"Reviews":[],"Id":5106},{"Name":"Album Title","Price":0.0,"NewPrice":0.0,"ShortDescription":"Can curiosity may end shameless explained. True high on said mr on come.","SKU":"","ProductTypeID":0,"ImageID":2,"Promotion":"","ParentID":0,"Attributes":"","Image":{"Path":"http://demo.neontheme.com/assets/images/album-thumb-1.jpg","Id":2},"Reviews":[],"Id":5107},{"Name":"Album Title","Price":0.0,"NewPrice":0.0,"ShortDescription":"Can curiosity may end shameless explained. True high on said mr on come.","SKU":"","ProductTypeID":0,"ImageID":2,"Promotion":"","ParentID":0,"Attributes":"","Image":{"Path":"http://demo.neontheme.com/assets/images/album-thumb-1.jpg","Id":2},"Reviews":[],"Id":5108},{"Name":"Album Title","Price":0.0,"NewPrice":0.0,"ShortDescription":"Can curiosity may end shameless explained. True high on said mr on come.","SKU":"","ProductTypeID":0,"ImageID":2,"Promotion":"","ParentID":0,"Attributes":"","Image":{"Path":"http://demo.neontheme.com/assets/images/album-thumb-1.jpg","Id":2},"Reviews":[],"Id":5109},{"Name":"Album Title","Price":0.0,"NewPrice":0.0,"ShortDescription":"Can curiosity may end shameless explained. True high on said mr on come.","SKU":"","ProductTypeID":0,"ImageID":2,"Promotion":"","ParentID":0,"Attributes":"","Image":{"Path":"http://demo.neontheme.com/assets/images/album-thumb-1.jpg","Id":2},"Reviews":[],"Id":5110}]
        });
    }());
</script>
```

In my console I am getting,

```
/%7B%7Bproduct.Image.Path%7D%7D 404 (Not Found) at <img src="{{product.Image.Path}}" />
```

I am not seeing anything. Chrome Html Tab shows me this,

```
<div class="gallery-env ng-scope" ng-app="s" np-controller="ProductCtrl">
    <!-- ngRepeat: product in products -->
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried ng-src instead of src at the img tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1** Typo in controller:

`np-controller="ProductCtrl"` --> `ng-controller`

**2**
Use *ngSrc* instead

`<img data-ng-src="{{product.Image.Path}}" />`

Comment: data-ng-src or ng-src

Answer (score 2):

You have to use ngSrc:

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc

From the doc:

> Using Angular markup like {{hash}} in a src attribute doesn't work
>   right: The browser will fetch from the URL with the literal text
>   {{hash}} until Angular replaces the expression inside {{hash}}. The
>   ngSrc directive solves this problem.

so:

```
<img data-ng-src="{{product.Image.Path}}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you should use `<img ng-src='...'>`

secondly you have typo in `div class="gallery-env" ng-app="s" nP-controller="ProductCtrl">`

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HBu2g/)